# Validating and totaling the sum of user input with JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My goal is to take user input in the forms: First name, Last name, Phone number, Product 1, Product 2, and Product 3. Then with a button called Calculate, it will both validate all the forms and add the total value of products 1, 2, and 3.

I can get as far as validating the forms but my code will not print the total.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["First name"].value;
      var y = document.forms["myForm"]["Last name"].value;
      var Z = document.forms["myForm"]["Phone"].value;
      var amount1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount1").value);
      var amount2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount2").value);
      var amount3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount3").value);
      if (x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
      }
      if (y == "") {
        alert("Last name must be filled out");
        return false;
      }
      if (Z == "") {
        alert("Phone number must be filled out");
        return false;
      }
      if (isNaN(amount1)) {
        alert("Please enter the amount for product 1");
        return false;
      }
      if (isNaN(amount2)) {
        alert("Please enter the amount for product 2");
        return false;
      }
      if (isNaN(amount3)) {
        alert("Please enter the amount for product 3");
         return false;
}
      var total = amount1 + amount2 + amount3;
      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = total;


    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="myForm">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="First name"> <br> <br> Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last name"><br> <br> Phone Number: <input type="text" name="Phone"> <br> <br> Product 1: <input type="text" id="amount1"> <br> <br> Product 2:
    <input
      type="text" id="amount2"> <br> <br> Product 3: <input type="text" id="amount3"> <br> <br>
      <br>
      <input onclick="validateForm()" type="button" value="Calculate">
  </form>
  <p id="p1"> (Results) </p>


</body>

</html>
```

Edited with the errors found in the comments, however the problem remains that the total won't print.

Comment: does browser console shows errors?

Comment: No. If the fields are empty the browser will alert the user they cant be, and if they are filled correctly then nothing happens. The end goal is to just print the total of the 3 product values.

Comment: It is working for me in the browser. I also added console.log(total) and it showed the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that the function to get a element is `getElementById` instead of `GetElementById`, so change this

```
var amount1 = parseInt(document.GetElementById("amount1").value);
var amount2 = parseInt(document.GetElementById("amount2").value);
var amount3 = parseInt(document.GetElementById("amount3").value);
```

to

```
var amount1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount1").value);
var amount2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount2").value);
var amount3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount3").value);
```

And also the inputs are missing the `id`, so change them with

```
  Product 1: <input type="text" id="amount1"> <br> <br>
  Product 2: <input type="text" id="amount2"> <br> <br>
  Product 3: <input type="text" id="amount3"> <br> <br>
```

And as the last point, in your condition  you are using `Prod1, Prod2, Prod3`, where your variables are `amount1, amount2, amount3`, so they should be like this:

```
if (isNaN(amount1)) {
  alert("Please enter the amount for product 1");
  return false;
}
if (isNaN(amount2)) {
  alert("Please enter the amount for product 2");
  return false;
}
if (isNaN(amount3)) {
  alert("Please enter the amount for product 3");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The three errors you found were actually added while I was troubleshooting and forgot to fix them when I changed the code around. Unfortunately even after fixing them it still won't print the total.

Comment: no problem, if this fix your issue, mark as correct in order to close this question

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use `parseInt`/`parseFloat` on text data you'll need to check for `NaN` values (since those functions turn strings into either numbers or `NaN`).
So I'll suggest using `isNaN(amount1)` instead of `amount1 == ""` (which will never be true.

See my edit on Alberto's answer.